# Java method not calculating

Tags: java

I am writing a method which calculates the commission a company gives its vendor for a given product, however it is not executing. Please help. Here are the guidelines that I have to follow.

This function calculates the commission a company gives its vendor for a given product. The commission is calculated as follows (I can safely assume amount is greater than 0):

If it is an annual license, the rates are:

- 10% if sale is between $0 and $1,000
- 15% if sale is between $1,001 and $10,000
- 20% if sale is above $10,000

If it is a forever license (not an annual one), the rates are:

- 10% if sale is between $0 and $10,000
- 15% if sale is between $10,001 and $50,000
- 20% if sale is above $50,000

I attempted to write the above logic into the following code:

```
public static int commissionRate(boolean isAnnualLicense, int saleAmount) {
   if (isAnnualLicense == true){
        if (saleAmount <= 1000){
            return commissionRate(true,10);
        } else if (saleAmount >= 1001 && saleAmount <= 10000) {
            return commissionRate(true,15);
        } else if (saleAmount > 10001) {
            return commissionRate(true,20);
        } else {
            if (isAnnualLicense == false) {
                if (saleAmount >= 10000) {
                    return commissionRate(false,10);
                } else if (saleAmount >= 100001 && saleAmount <= 50000) {
                    return commissionRate(false, 15);
                } else if (saleAmount >= 50001) {
                    return commissionRate(false,20);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

This is what it is supposed to be executing:

```
public void testCommission(){
    Assert.assertEquals("commision for annual sales, 1,000 should be 10", 10, Assignment3.commissionRate(true,1000));
    Assert.assertEquals("commision for annual sales, 1,001 should be 15", 15, Assignment3.commissionRate(true,1001));
    Assert.assertEquals("commision for annual sales, 10,000 should be 15", 15, Assignment3.commissionRate(true,10000));
    Assert.assertEquals("commision for annual sales, 10,001 should be 20", 20, Assignment3.commissionRate(true,10001));
    Assert.assertEquals("commision for OneTime sales, 10,000 should be 10", 10, Assignment3.commissionRate(false,10000));
    Assert.assertEquals("commision for OneTime sales, 10,001 should be 15", 15, Assignment3.commissionRate(false,10001));
    Assert.assertEquals("commision for OneTime sales, 50,000 should be 15", 15, Assignment3.commissionRate(false,50000));
    Assert.assertEquals("commision for OneTime sales, 50,001 should be 20", 20, Assignment3.commissionRate(false,50001));
}

@Grade(points=25)
@Test
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What isn't executing? What do you mean 'not executing'?

Comment: I added what it is suppose to be executing. Sorry I'm rusty with my Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will never reach the `isAnnualLicense == false` part, because it is at the wrong nesting level. It should be like this:

```
if (isAnnualLicense){
    if (saleAmount <= 1000){
        return 10;
    } else if (saleAmount >= 1001 && saleAmount <= 10000) {
        return 15;
    } else { // saleAmount > 10001
        return 20;
    }
} else {
    if (saleAmount <= 10000) {
        return 10;
    } else if (saleAmount >= 100001 && saleAmount <= 50000) {
        return 15;
    } else { // saleAmount >= 50001
        return 20;
    }
}
```

You can further simplify this by assigning commision rate to a variable, and making a single `return` at the bottom of your method:

```
int rate;
if (isAnnualLicense){
    if (saleAmount <= 1000){
        rate = 10;
    } else if (saleAmount >= 1001 && saleAmount <= 10000) {
        rate = 15;
    } else { // saleAmount > 10001
        rate = 20;
    }
} else {
    if (saleAmount <= 10000) {
        rate = 10;
    } else if (saleAmount >= 100001 && saleAmount <= 50000) {
        rate = 15;
    } else { // saleAmount >= 50001
        rate = 20;
    }
}
return rate;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm suppose to get 25 points for this executing and it is still not giving me the points. Any help is appreciated please thanks.

Comment: @rls1982 I see what you are doing - the method is calling itself, and it's not supposed to do it. Take a look at the edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is still not working. What can I do now? I appreciate your help. I have to get this right

Comment: @rls1982 Which test is failing?

Comment: I'm using GitBash so it isn't really telling me it is just saying that I got 0 out of 25 points.

Comment: @rls1982 Did you try running your `testCommission` unit test method?

Comment: No I use ./gradlew grade in GitBash. This is for school and I have to use that way of validating to get all of my points

Comment: @rls1982 You need to set your own unit tests or tests of some sort to see what's happening. You also had `>=` in place of `<=` in the first `if` of the `else` branch (see the edit).

Comment: This is for school, so that was set for me. Is there anything else that I can do? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @rls1982 Did you see the edit?

Comment: You mean the edit to your code? If so yes and I still can't get it to work

Comment: You are the Man! There was an extra zero in 10001 I removed it and it worked. Thanks again seriously!